# Launch separate process in Qt

Tags: python, c++, qt

I'm attempting to run an python file from a Qt application however I have two problems. One it does not appear to launch the python tool. And secondly when I try doing a simple test using just notepad as an example, i notice that Notepad closes when i close my application. I'm not sure why the python tool is not launching and why the process is not truly independent from the Qt application.

```
else if(QFileInfo(path).isFile() && path.endsWith(".py", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
{
    QProcess::startDetached("C:/python27/python.exe", QStringList() << "C:/Users/john/testing.py");

    QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
    proc->startDetached("notepad.exe");
}
```

**Update #1**: Second attempt still failing....
I've research a bit more and even attempted the code below and it's now giving me the error:

> ImportError: No module named site

Which is confusing to me because I'm setting the env paths. At the end of the day all im trying to do is run a shell command like the following, but from Qt.

```
"C:/python27/python.exe" "C:/Users/john/testing.py"
```

Latest code:

```
QString program( "C:\\Python27\\python.exe" );
QStringList args = QStringList() << "C:\\Users\\jmartini\\Desktop\\Trash\\testing.py";

QProcess process;
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
env.insert("PYTHONHOME", "C:\\Python27");
env.insert("PYTHONPATH", "C:\\Python27\\Lib");
process.setProcessEnvironment(env);

process.execute(program, args);
```

Comment: startDetached returns a false in case of error. Did you check the return value?

Comment: what is odd is this works: QProcess::startDetached("notepad.exe", QStringList() << "C:/Users/john/testing.py"); but not when trying to call python

Comment: You should provide a canonical path to QProcess, which uses the syntax of the running OS. In order words, have you tried to type QProcess::startDetached(C:\\python27\\python.exe") ?

Comment: @S.Monteleone ive updated the question with the latest findings.

Comment: Well clearly the issue was the path string used wrong slashes. Now, about python complaining, is there any reason why the python script is now in a different location ? Is it the same script?

Comment: I was just trying different python scripts. it should not matter where the python script lives itself.

Comment: Indeed. But as they say, the devil is in the details. :) Try using the start method instead of execute. Execute is the static one, hence it will ignore the environment. Please let me know if this solves the issue and I will write a full answer.

Comment: @S.Monteleone no luck. Nothing appears to happen or even print to the logger console.

Comment: I'm quite baffled that something so simple to do in cmd and python and C# is becoming quite a headache.

Comment: I wonder if there is a need for me to set the current working directory to be that of the python file itself. Is that something with qprocess?

Comment: Nothing appears in console because the stderr and stdout of your process (the Python interpreter in this case) are redirected. You can use the QProcess::readyReadStandardError() signal to read the stderr (there's another one for the stdout). Then you can use the same interface as the QIODevice. Test it with a python script that shows a message box: if you see it, then it is starting fine. Also, the process will be attached, so your Qt app must be open the whole time, otherwise the child process will be killed.

Comment: How can i make the python file execute under a different process so i can eventually close the main app without affecting the child process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169267/discussion-between-s-monteleone-and-jokermartini).

Comment: call setProgram(), setArgument() and then startDetached()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recap the details enlisted in the various comments and provide the final solution for your question.

**Paths and backslashes**

The QProcess API uses the **CreateProcess** on Win32 platforms and therefore paths must be provided in accordance with the OS convention (using backslashes instead of slashes). In your example, "C:/python27/python.exe" must be converted to "C:\Python27\python.exe". The double backslash here is due to C++ string literals escaping.

**Environment**

As you have correctly noted in your update, you need to set a few environment variables in order to make the Python interpreter work as expected.

You also specified you want to **detach** the invoked python script, so it can run even when your application is closed.

This is trickier with Qt < 5.10 as the appropriate API to accomplish this task was introduced **with Qt 5.10** (see [this](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/08/25/a-new-qprocessstartdetached/) post from the Qt blog).

With Qt 5.10, the correct code is:

```
QProcess process;

// set the environment variables
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
env.insert("PYTHONHOME", "C:\\Python27");
env.insert("PYTHONPATH", "C:\\Python27\\Lib");
process.setProcessEnvironment(env);

// set program name and args
process.setProgram("C:\\Python27\\python.exe");
process.setArguments(args);

// start the detached process
process.startDetached();
```

The code you have in your updated answer doesn't work because it is using the **static** execute() method. You see, a static method is part of a class, and this means you can call it from an object instance of that class, however, since it's static, it can't access the object's members. In other words, execute() can't know anything about the QProcessEnvironment you set before.

For the same reason, calling the startDetached() overload which accepts two arguments won't work either, because it is static too.

The Qt blog post explains exactly why this new non static overload was created, and this fits perfectly in your scenario.

**Closing my app kills the python interpreter.**

This is true if you run your Qt app in **debug**. That's because the detached process (the python interpreter in this case) is **attached to the debugger too**, and since the debugging session is closed when your Qt app is closed, this kills python too.

However, if you run your deployed app (double click on the exe, not from the debugger) it should work as expected.